# Unexpected end of JSON input moodle

Tags: moodle

In moodle I am getting the following error on enrolling the user. But, User get enrolled in course when we check refresh the page but It shows the error on enrolling. 
Also I am using role_assigned event in my custom auth block .Whenever I enroll user in course from enrollment methods the event get called succefully but when I try to enroll user in course from enrolled users my event doesnt get called and the error get displayed.

[image]

[image]

Please help me out.

Comment: show your json content

Answer (score 0):

The most typical reason is that you have debugging messages printed in the response from the server. Open your Web Developer Tools and inspect the request in Network tab. Check that the response from the server is valid JSON.